# How to UNDO/REDO shapes drawn on the canvas in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am an intermediate to android developing and I were given a module of an app which includes all the operations of the canvas i.e. free drawing, shapes and text. I have done with the free drawing and its undo/redo operations. But i am not able to figure out how to undo redo shapes drawn on the canvas.
When i use the methods : canvas.drawRect(args) it goes fine same in the case of circle, arc etc but i am not able to delete those from the canvas.
If i use Path.addRect(args) and draw in onDraw() then the shape is not rendered when i am dragging to draw when i take off finger then shape appears.
below is my DrawView class : 
Thanks in advance!

```
class DrawView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {


    companion object {
        val TYPE_LINE = 0
        val TYPE_RECT = 1
        val TYPE_CIRCLE = 2
    }

    val DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.WHITE

    private var startX = 0f
    private var startY = 0f
    private var endX = 0f
    private var endY = 0f
    private var drawType: Int = 0
    private val TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4f
    private var mX = 0f
    private var mY: Float = 0f
    private var mPath: Path? = null
    private var mPaint: Paint? = null
    private var currentColor = Color.BLUE
    private var defaultBgColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR
    private var strokeWidth = 10f
    private var mBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    private var mCanvas: Canvas? = null
    private val mBitmapPaint = Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG)

    private val paths: ArrayList<PathHolder> = ArrayList()
    private val undo: ArrayList<PathHolder> = ArrayList()

    init {
        mPaint = Paint()
        mPaint!!.isAntiAlias = true
        mPaint!!.isDither = true
        mPaint!!.color = currentColor
        mPaint!!.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mPaint!!.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        mPaint!!.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        mPaint!!.xfermode = null
        mPaint!!.alpha = 0xff
    }

    fun initialise(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics) {
        val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
        val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        mCanvas = Canvas(mBitmap!!)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.save()
        mCanvas!!.drawColor(defaultBgColor)

        for (draw in paths) {
            mPaint!!.color = draw.color 
            mPaint!!.strokeWidth = draw.strokeWidth
            mPaint!!.maskFilter = null
            mCanvas!!.drawPath(draw.path, mPaint!!)
        }

        when(drawType){
            TYPE_RECT -> onDrawRectangle()
            TYPE_CIRCLE -> onDrawCircle()
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap!!, 0f, 0f, mBitmapPaint)
        canvas.restore()
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val x = event.x
        val y = event.y
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                touchStart(x, y)
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                touchUp()
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                touchMove(x, y)
                invalidate()
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun touchStart(x: Float, y: Float) {
        startX = x ; startY = y
        mPath = Path()
        val path = PathHolder(currentColor, strokeWidth, mPath!!)
        paths.add(path)
        mPath!!.reset()
        mPath!!.moveTo(x, y)
        mX = x
        mY = y
    }

    private fun touchMove(x: Float, y: Float) {
        endX = x ; endY = y
        val dx = abs(x - mX)
        val dy: Float = abs(y - mY)
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            if ( drawType == TYPE_LINE )
                mPath!!.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2)
            mX = x
            mY = y
        }
    }

    private fun touchUp() {
        if ( drawType == TYPE_LINE )
            mPath!!.lineTo(mX, mY)
        /*val path = Path()
        path.addRect(startX, startY, endX, endY, Path.Direction.CW)
        paths.add(PathHolder( currentColor, strokeWidth, path ))
        Toast.makeText(context, "${paths.size}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()*/
    }

    fun clear() {
        paths.clear()
        invalidate()
    }

    fun undo() {
        if (paths.size > 0) {
            undo.add(paths.removeAt(paths.size - 1))
            invalidate() // add
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Nothing to undo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    fun redo() {
        if (undo.size > 0) {
            paths.add(undo.removeAt(undo.size - 1))
            invalidate() // add
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Nothing to undo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    fun setStrokeWidth(width: Float) {
        strokeWidth = width
    }

    fun setColor(color: Int) {
        currentColor = color
    }

    fun setDrawType(drawType: Int) {
        this.drawType = drawType
    }

    private fun onDrawCircle() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mCanvas!!.drawArc(startX, startY, endX, endY, 360f, 360f, false, mPaint!!)
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "not available in Android:${Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun onDrawRectangle() {
        mCanvas!!.drawRect(startX, startY, endX, endY, mPaint!!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a path in `TOUCH_START` and add shapes in that path in `ACTION_MOVE` and reset the cordinates in `TOUCH_UP` like:

TOUCH_DOWN:

```
mPath = Path()
    mPath!!.moveTo(startX, startY)
    val path = PathHolder(currentColor, currentFillColor, strokeWidth, mPath!!)
    paths.add(path)
    isDown = true
```

TOUCH_MOVE:

```
mPath!!.reset()
                val left = min(startX, endX)
                val right = max(startX, endX)
                val top = min(startY, endY)
                val bottom = max(startY, endY)
                mPath!!.addRect(left, top, right, bottom, Path.Direction.CCW)
```

TOUCH_DOWN:

```
if (isDown) {
        startX = 0F
        startY = 0F
        isDown = false
    }
```

Comment: whao! 
Worked like a charm :)
Thanks